# Active Record without Rails: How to pass an Arbitrary hash to Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, hash

I'm trying to pass the following Hash to Active Record to save:

```
[{
  "id"=>"WSECOUT", 
  "realtime_start"=>"2013-02-10", 
  "realtime_end"=>"2013-02-10", 
  "title"=>"Reserve Bank Credit - Securities Held Outright", 
  "observation_start"=>"1989-03-22", 
  "observation_end"=>"2013-02-06", 
  "frequency"=>"Weekly, Ending Wednesday", 
  "frequency_short"=>"W", 
  "units"=>"Billions of Dollars", 
  "units_short"=>"Bil. of $", 
  "seasonal_adjustment"=>"Not Seasonally Adjusted", 
  "seasonal_adjustment_short"=>"NSA", 
  "last_updated"=>"2013-02-08 08:32:33-06", 
  "popularity"=>"42", 
  "notes"=>"The amount of securities held by Federal Reserve Banks. This quantity is the cumulative result of permanent open market operations: outright purchases or sales of securities, conducted by the Federal Reserve. Section 14 of the Federal Reserve Act defines the securities that the Federal Reserve is authorized to buy and sell."
  }]
```

My ruby class looks like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_record'  
require 'logger'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(  
:adapter => "mysql2",  
:host => "localhost",  
:username => "root",
:password => "*********",
:database => "fred"  
)  

class Series < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :id, :realtime_start, :realtime_end, :title, :observation_start,
              :observation_end, :frequency, :frequency_short, :units, :units_short, 
              :seasonal_adjustment, :seasonal_adjustment_short, :last_updated, 
              :popularity, :notes

end

require_relative 'wsecout'
@series = Wsecout.new.getSeries "wsecout"
@series = @series['series']

test = Series.create(@series)
```

The @series variable contains the Hash.  When I run this code, the object is created as is the row in mysql, however, there is no data in the fields.  I know I'm missing a step here, but I am unable to figure out which step.  Also, is there going to be a problem with my Hash containing an id, because Active Record creates it's own id?

Comment: If your first example is right, then @series contains an Array with one Hash. Try `@series['series'][0]` or something. Alternatively you could post the output of `puts @series['series'].inspect`.

Comment: That worked thanks.  Any idea on how to map the :id in the Hash to a different :id than the Action Record :id?  In this case the hash has an "id" of 'WSECOUT'.  Is there a way to map that "id" to a new field called :series_id at the time I use Series.create(@series)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to your second question "map that "id" to a new field called :series_id":

```
@series['series'][0]['series_id'] = @series['series'][0]['id']
@series['series'][0].delete('id')
```

Or if you want to change multiple keys based on some criteria, then use it in the if condition as below:

```
@series['series'][0].keys.each do |k|
  if(k == 'id')
    @series['series'][0]['series_id'] = @series['series'][0][k]
    @series['series'][0].delete(k)
  end
end
```

This will iterate through each key of the hash and if the key matches to `id` then it add another key `series_id` with the same value and delete the `id`.

Comment: I tried this replacing the 'h' with @series and received the following error: '`block in <main>': unexpected return (LocalJumpError)'

Comment: Oh my bad! Just updated the answer, removed the return statement

Comment: First thanks for the help!  This worked perfectly and I'm updating my original question to reflect your changes.

Comment: Hey.. I have updated my answer again. just check it. I just felt that it doesn't make sense to loop through the hash keys in your case. :)